# Firebase web client gzip upload to Cloud Storage

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-storage, gzip, firebase-storage

I am using the Firebase web client and would like to upload a gzipped file to Cloud Storage. With the Nodejs client it is possible to simply specify gzip as an option like so: `await bucket.upload(filepath, { destination, gzip: true });`. Is it possible to gzip data upload to Cloud Storage using the Firebase web client? For example, how would I change the following to gzip the file?

```js
const ref = firebase.storage().ref().child("test.json");
const blob = new Blob([JSON.stringify({ hello: "world" })], { type: "application/json" });
await ref.put(blob);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/upload-files#upload_files) which shows you a sample to upload a picture:

```
// Create a root reference
var storageRef = firebase.storage().ref();

// Create a reference to 'mountains.jpg'
var mountainsRef = storageRef.child('mountains.jpg');

// Create a reference to 'images/mountains.jpg'
var mountainImagesRef = storageRef.child('images/mountains.jpg');

// While the file names are the same, the references point to different files
mountainsRef.name === mountainImagesRef.name            // true
mountainsRef.fullPath === mountainImagesRef.fullPath    // false

// Create file metadata including the content type
var metadata = {
contentType: 'image/jpeg',
};

// Upload the file and metadata
var uploadTask = storageRef.child('images/mountains.jpg').put(file, metadata);
```

But in your case you may want to upload gzip file. Just change the metadata.

Comment: I think OP is looking for an example of *how to uploadg their existing JSON file* to Storage as gzip (so to save bandwidth on the transfer).

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen actually I am not bothered whether it is zipped client or server side, I only want to make sure it is gzipped in Cloud Storage in order to save costs. At the moment I am sending the data to a Cloud Function in order to gzip it before uploading to Cloud Storage. But I would like to get rid of the Cloud Function if possible, again in order to save costs.